# sample postgresql-simple-migration program does not compile

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to get started with the `postgresql-simple-migration` library, and am having trouble getting a listed sample program to compile.

The sample program, shown below, is the "Initializing the database" example listed on the [`postgresql-simple-migration` hackage page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-migration).

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let url = "host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pw"
    con <- connectPostgreSQL (BS8.pack url)
    withTransaction con $ runMigration $
        MigrationContext MigrationInitialization True con
```

It seems all I should need to do for this to compile is import the correct modules. Importing `postgresql-simple-migration` modules containing these terms and `Data.ByteString.Char8` which makes `pack` have the expected types, gives the following.

```
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.Migration
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS8

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let url = "host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pw"
    con <- connectPostgreSQL (BS8.pack url)
    withTransaction con $ runMigration $
        MigrationContext MigrationInitialization True con
```

However, attempting to compile this results in a type error.

```
$ stack build
Building all executables for `db' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
db-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library db-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'db-exe' for db-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/db-exe/db-exe-tmp/Main.o )

/home/matthew/backup/organizeactions/taskmasterplatform/db/app/Main.hs:12:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘MigrationResult String’ with ‘()’
      Expected type: IO ()
        Actual type: IO (MigrationResult String)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        withTransaction con
        $ runMigration $ MigrationContext MigrationInitialization True con
      In the expression:
        do { let url = "host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pw";
             con <- connectPostgreSQL (pack url);
             withTransaction con
             $ runMigration
               $ MigrationContext MigrationInitialization True con }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { let url = ...;
                   con <- connectPostgreSQL (pack url);
                   withTransaction con
                   $ runMigration
                     $ MigrationContext MigrationInitialization True con }

--  While building custom Setup.hs for package db-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/matthew/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build lib:db exe:db-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

`runMigration` (of [`Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.Migration`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-migration-0.1.11.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-Migration.html)) has type

```
`runMigration :: MigrationContext -> IO (MigrationResult String)`
```

and the `(MigrationResult String)` does not match the `()` marked in the type signature for `main`.

**Why is the example not compiling?**

- Do I need to import from a different module?
- Does the example contain an error?

Comment: You can probably fix it by replacing `withTransaction con $ runMigration` with `withTransaction con $ void $ runMigration` where `void` is imported from Control.Monad. Void discards the result of a monadic computation.

Comment: @Zpalmtree that does work to get it to compile. I wonder why the example is different.

Comment: It looks like it must be just a typo/mistake, I checked the hackage history and runMigration always had this type signature.